# Web scraping client abstraction - compatibility with future web API

Tags: web-scraping, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a client for a web site, which will scrap this website for data.

What I would like to do, is to design API of this client in the way, that it could be used without modifications, if a web API was created in the future.

Currently the website does not provide any web API. It does use AJAX, so parts of its functionality can be easily reused within the client.

The biggest issue I'm dealing with now, is that some data is not identified by integers. Instead a string is used, which describes name of the object. So, if I were to use integer in the abstraction and string in web scraping implementation, I would have to use some sort of mapping between integers and strings.

So my question is: should I continue trying to create a "perfect" abstraction for the client? Or should I just create web scraping client and if/when web API is available, I would create a new client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you are wondering if it is worthwhile to create in intermediate API which your client talks to, and then the intermediate API does the web scraping:

`client-->API-->Web Site`

Then when the Web site creates an API, your API would talk to it without modifications to the client:

`client-->API-->Web Site API`

versus just continuing to have the client scrape the web site directly until the web site provides an API:

`client-->Web Site`

And then have the client talk to the API:

`client-->Web Site API`

It's difficult to give you an answer without understanding your situation, but here are some considerations that can help you make decision:

- How difficult will it be to update the client?  If there are many clients or its difficult to update them, then hiding some logic in your own API makes sense.
- How likely is it that the Web Site API will match directly to your API? You may need to change your client anyway if your API doesn't fit with the web site API.
- Will some other website provide a better or cheaper service?  If so you could switch to that other website with less impact on the client by using an API.